# Umbraco - Editable List view inside detail view of Document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7, document-types

I want to create a list of messages (subject, body and some boolean flags). I need to make it function like the users (back office) will be presented to 2 textboxes (subject and body) and some checkboxes. They will enter the data and click on any Add button so this will be added inside the list. Users can edit and delete the items from the list.

I know the document types have a list view representation. But I need to have this functionality inside the detail view of a document type (under a tab).

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by users, are you referring to umbraco backoffice users or you want to add this functionality to frontend so members can do such a thing ?

Comment: It sounds backoffice to me. I would say you have to create a custom property editor.

Comment: Nested content to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out. Created nested content, making my Message document type as listview. Then I added other child items and assigned them in listview content property in a tab.